# OLTP type data in a OLAP system

Tags: sql, database, olap, oltp

We have an OLAP system at work Snowflake. We have put OLTP data in it and the business users are trying to use it as a mixture of OLTP and OLAP. I know this is wrong but need to know if there are any issues with this before we pull the OLTP data out and back into an Oracle instance.

Comment: Snowflake is a Data Warehous sytem, not OLTP. The company Snowflake itself doesn't claim to be an OLTP DBMS

Comment: Yep - so what happens if you put data from an OLTP DBMS into Snowflake, and try to use Snowflake as OLTP? I know it’s wrong, I just want to know what happens when used incorrectly like this?

Comment: It's probably sloooooooow compared to the same load on an OLTP system :-)

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you're looking for, but generally there are 3 groups of issues:

1. performance (as someone mentioned above). Snowflake is not meant for this kind of loads so stuff like single-row inserts or updates if done in bulk are going to be slow
2. space considerations. Snowflake partitions are immutable. So every time you do a single-row insert or update it creates a new partition and old one falls into time travel/failsafe. If you do that often enough your deleted data is going to take way more space than current
3. constraints other than NOT NULL not being enforced. Not sure how important that is for your DB